# Send entire dropdown to another aspx page using User session

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I wish to send all the values in my dropdown from one page to another using a Session.

On the target page, I will be binding the Session to the dropdwon over there.
WHat Can I use? a Dataset, List(Of Strings), Array.
I guess, Populating a dataset from all the dropdown values, and storing the dataset in session will also do the trick.
How can i achieve this.

I am storing the all the values in an ArraryList

```
 Dim lstAgeAsOf As New ArrayList
    For Each item As ListItem In AgeAsOfDropDown.Items
                lstAgeAsOf.Add(item)
            Next
            Session("AgeAsOf") = lstAgeAsOf
```

On the next page,

```
Dim lstAgeAsOf As New ArrayList
        lstAgeAsOf = Session("AgeAsOf")
```

But, This has some conversion error

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Store your datasource in session from which you are binding dropdown in first page so when you will go to second page you will have that datasource in session and you can get it from session.

First Page

```
dropdown.DataSource=yourdatasource;
dropdown.DataBind();
Session["datasrc"]=yourdatasource;
```

Second page

```
dropdown.DataSource=Session["datasrc"];
dropdown.DataBind();
```

You will need to cast session value in the type you have stored from first page.If you have stored dataset you will cast session as DataSet

```
DataSet ds=(DataSet)Session["datasrc"];
dropdown.DataSource=ds;
dropdown.DataBind();
```

And same for any other type you have stored.